# Why does predict function give out NA in its response?

Tags: r, prediction, linearmodels

I prepared a model with R's inbuilt `glm`. After the model was created, I passed the `model` and `testData` to `predict` function. The code is as follows:

```
data = read.csv(file = "twitter-dataset.csv")
testData = read.csv(file = "twitter-test-dataset.csv")

model = glm(formula = viral ~ sentiment + postLength + hashTagCount + contentURLCount + likeCount + shareCount + followersCount + followingCount + tweetCount + gender + peakVelocity, data = data)


predict(model, testData)
```

The output of predict function is what I did not understand. It includes `NA`. The sample output on the console from `predict` is shown below:

```
    1            2            3            4            5            6            7 
  -0.261160126 -0.475512528  0.248612361 -0.384309806 -0.023267727 -0.238602913           NA 
  8            9           10           11           12           13           14 
  NA           NA           NA -0.225554686           NA -0.477842906 -0.192178793 
  15           16           17           18           19           20           21 
  NA -0.207955059 -0.172670264           NA -0.123026836 -0.026680875  0.120059375 
  22           23           24           25           26           27           28
```

What could be the reason for this? Also, how could I check the accuracy of the model?

**Update:**

Dataset: [input data set](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UfWehQo8D3ObodDL4ptWxVc4t6_R-40_2V9sGFKzUP4/edit?usp=sharing)

Test Dataset: [test data set](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/113Wr8LMoDcZKMEPZHrwbp3cof4rZU2xBnqa7d4Zx_GM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: There are several reasons why this might happen, but the specific one in your case will be impossible to tell without direct access to your data, in the form of a reproducible example.

Comment: @joran Have updated with the data set links to google spreadsheet

Comment: When I run your model on that data and then `predict` I get no NAs.

Comment: @joran Did you use the same parameters I used in `glm`? [Screenshot of what I get](https://ibb.co/k7x32o)

Comment: @joran Also why does it output in decimal when `viral` has only 3 values 1,0,-1?

Comment: I ran your `glm` code exactly; no NAs. For your other question, read the documentation for `?predict.glm` and pay special attention to the `type` argument.

Comment: ...but setting the NA issue asside what kind of `glm` exactly did you think you were fitting with a response variable that has three levels? Because in your code you're just using the default gaussian link. It's all very odd. Did you think you were fitting a multinomial model (for three levels in the response)? Did you think you were fitting a logistic regression (which would be odd, since your response doesn't have two levels)?

Comment: @joran I want to fit a multinomial model for the three levels in the response.

Comment: In that case I would do some googling on that topic, because `glm` is the wrong function for that. I think there's a package called `mlogit`, and maybe a function in **nnet**. Possibly in **MASS** as well. You'll also want `viral` to be an explicit factor.

Comment: @joran Okay. What do you mean by `explicit factor`?

Comment: `viral <- factor(viral)`